# Drop all rows that share a certain name in a column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe (df), that is made up of several columns. One of these columns is called 'CODE', and is made up the names 'A', 'B', 'C', and 'D' that pop up many times throughout the rows. Essentially, my goal is to drop all rows 'D' is the name in the column 'CODE'. I know I can't do a simple drop, becasue i'm not trying to get rid of the column, i'm trying to remove any row that has this specific name in a certain column. I hope this makes some sense!

Comment: Please include (1) an example of the dataframe, (2) the expected output, and (3) your code that (presumably) did not work.

Comment: `df = df[df['CODE']!='D']`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas)

Answer (score 4):

You can create a new dataframe that excludes all rows that have 'D' in the 'CODE' column:

```
df = df[df['CODE']!='D']
```

Answer (score 0):

What about selecting all other rows that are not equal to that name you wanna discard?

```
df = df[df['CODE'] != 'D']
```

Comment: Why the downvote? because I asked for acceptance? Anyway, the answer is correct and therefore a downvote isn't funny at all.

Answer (score 0):

Should be simple as-

```
df = df[df.column_name != "something"]
```